# How to fix cell format as excel cell is losing format after executing macro

Tags: excel, excel-2003, dde, vba

Hi i am populating data into excel worksheet using DDE.Execute command from Oracle forms. Code is fine but when I am executing the below macro **FORMAT_SECTION_TITLE_2** using DDE.Execute command it colors the line but also changes the Date to number and rather value of the cell appearing as a proper date it appears as **39234**

```
Sub FORMAT_SECTION_TITLE_2()

    With Selection.Interior
        .ColorIndex = 7
        .Pattern = xlSolid
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = False
End Sub
```

I have also tried to change lots of things but no help. please suggest.

Thanks

Update 1:
Siddharth I added a new sub in the excel sheet as you mentioned and my sheet name is the same as you mentioned Sheet1

```
Sub formatColumn()
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
End Sub
```

Comment: The above code is not responsible for the format change. You could try two things. Use this code before you start the process or after you have finished the process of exporting. `Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(5).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"` Change Sheet1 to the relevant sheet name and change 5 to the respective column number. Now try it

Comment: Siddharth, which code should I use before or after the process the one your mentioned or mine which I mentioned in my post. Also the problem is that due to some business condition we need to color the excel rows and my above code is doing what is expected but the only issue with my code is that it is disturbing the format of colored rows only. If i dont execute this macro to color the rows my data is in good shape in excel...please suggest

Comment: The code which I mentioned. Let me explain. If you put my code before your code then before exporting it will format the column for the relevant output. If you put it in the end then once your export finishes, the code will format the column as required. Try both one by one.

Comment: No Siddharth, I tried at the end of process. but no luck

Comment: Can you show the complete code that you tried? You can update the post above. Also a snapshot of the Sheet after the export?

Comment: Let's catch up here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10836/excelloosingformatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shax, as discovered after Two and half hours of chat, it appears to be an XY Problem :)

Like I mentioned above, the above code was not responsible for the formatting changes. The formatting was changed by another piece of code

```
Sub two_decimals()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
End Sub
```

The actual fault lies in the **oracle code** which was calling the `two_decimals` after the `FORMAT_SECTION_TITLE_2` I am not too good with oracle but when debugging it we found this problem.

BTW: Thanks to you, I learned few things in oracle today!